# Filtering big collection

Tags: c#, performance, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looping around **3000** employees & each employee loops for *all dates* of a month.

I have preloaded a List `ShiftDetails` from Db to improve the performance.

```
foreach (var item in lstEmp)
{
  while (fDate <= ToDate)
  {
    var employeeShifts = ShiftDetails
      .Where(a => a.EmployeeId == item.Id && a.ShiftDate == fDate)
      .Select(a => a)
      .FirstOrDefault();
  }
}
```

As I checked the performance with Profiler, the above line of code is eating up a big time.

Is there any way so that I can increase performance of my code?

I have searched & found that Dictionaries are best for tackling this but they should have unique keys, in my case I do not have any unique column in the List.

Comment: Can you speed it up by using the [Parallel.Foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx) approach?

Comment: how often do you increment `fDate` variable? is it `DateTime` object or some timestamp? Iterate over each millisecond could be much more painful than LINQ to 3000 objects

Comment: It is DateTime Object, for every employee it iterates for a month e.g. 1April-30APril.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see the combination of EmployeeId & ShiftDate could be your unique key.

Try to manually create the key using something like this :

```
var key = EmployeeId.ToString() + " - " + a.ShiftDate.ToString();
```

Then your search will be simply a line like this :

```
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
{
//  .. do your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this solution:

```
foreach (var item in lstEmp)
{
  var employeeShifts = ShiftDetails
      .Where(a => a.EmployeeId == item.Id && isInDate(a.ShiftDate))
      .Select(a => a)
      .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

At any other place in the code:

```
public bool isInDate(date start, date end, date dateFromUserProperty){
    //if dateFromUserProperty is within the range (start - end date) return true, 
    //else return false
}
```

Could you explain what item is? Are you trying to get an intersection between item collection and you user collection?

Answer (score 0):

I would split up your operations into two procedures:

- Filter by shifts for each `EmployeeId`
- Given the filtered shifts, filter by first `ShiftDate`

---

Filtering by `EmployeeId` outside the while loop is faster, because we only calculate this result once, instead of for each date in the month. Saving the result as `List` also gives us a slight performance gain, as we can utilize `List.Find` (which returns the first matching value for the given predicate, and is optimized for `List`s) instead of `Where`/`FirstOrDefault`.

```
foreach (var item in lstEmp)
{
    var shiftsByEmployeeId = ShiftDetails.Where(a => a.EmployeeId == item.Id).ToList();
    while (fDate <= ToDate)
    {
        var employeeShifts = shiftsByEmployeeId.Find(a => a.ShiftDate == fDate);
    }
}
```